# What causes Python error 'bad escape \C'?

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, python-3.7

I just wrote a function that will look at a text file and count all of the instances of True and False in the text file. Here is my file

```
ATOM     43  CA  LYS A   5      14.038  15.691  37.608  1.00 15.15           C      True
ATOM     52  CA  CYS A   6      16.184  12.782  38.807  1.00 16.72           C      True
ATOM     58  CA  GLU A   7      17.496  12.053  35.319  1.00 14.06           C      False
ATOM     67  CA  VAL A   8      18.375  15.721  34.871  1.00 12.27           C      True
ATOM     74  CA  PHE A   9      20.066  15.836  38.288  1.00 12.13           C      False
ATOM     85  CA  GLN A  10      22.355  12.978  37.249  1.00 12.54           C      False
```

And here is my code

```
def TFCount(txtFileName):   
    with open(txtFileName, 'r') as e:
        T = 0
        F = 0
        for record in e:
            if(re.search(r'^ATOM\s+\d+\s+\CA\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\w+\s+\T', record)):
                T += 1
            else:
                F += 1
        print(T)
        print(F)
```

I apologize if my regex is long and tedious to read, but this is the only way I know of counting the number of times True occurs in the file. As you can see, each time the program encounters True, it will add 1 to the variable T, otherwise it will add 1 to the variable False. After attempting to run the program, the interpreter returns error: bad escape \C. What does this error mean? And what in my code is causing it?

Comment: Why escape `C`? There is no `\C` regex escape. Beginning with Python 3.6, this is treated as an error. Before, it would have been parsed as a `C`. It looks like a typo on your part.

Comment: Not an escape sequence `\C`. Most engines will just unescape it as a pass, but apparently not Python. Or, it's probably a message from the interpreter.

Comment: Do you really need to parse the line that exactly? It seems like `'^ATOM.{80}T'` would work just as well and be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @MarkRansom have a very good point. PDB files have fixed columns by definition, so just checking for the value at some column is correct. In fact, a couple `substr` and equalities would do the trick without having to rely on regexps. Extract columns 1-6 and compare against `ATOM  `, extract columns 13-16 and compare against ` CA `. If it is the expected line, check for the `T` in its own column (http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM).

Answer (score 3):

You have `\C` in the first part of the regex

```
r'^ATOM\s+\d+\s+\CA
```

you should write just CA

```
r'^ATOM\s+\d+\s+CA
```

without escaping.

Later you have the same with `\T`.

`\X` means escaped `X` and most of the time is a special sequence in regex, e.g. `\d` for a digit or `\s` for a whitespace.

Comment: What if I have it part of my path variable  value example: `re.sub(x[0],rdstpath,path)`

Comment: What is the value of this variable?

Comment: It can be anything in a path '\something', for my case I have folders beginning with capital letters

Comment: You can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to prepare the value