# Regular expression working in Python3.5.2, not 3.7.4

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5, python-3.7

I am using a modified library I found on the web, for parsing .stl files.  It's been working wonderfully so far, in non-Anaconda Python 3.5.2.  I recently had to upgrade to Anaconda Python3.7.4.  The following line works well in 3.5, but throws an exception in 3.7.4

```
re.compile(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(\e[-+]?[0-9]+)?')
```

What is the reason for this?
The exception is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-08df04adea1a> in <module>
----> 1 re.compile(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(\e[-+]?[0-9]+)?')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in compile(pattern, flags)
    232 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    233     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a Pattern object."
--> 234     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    235 
    236 def purge():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    284     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    285         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 286     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    287     if not (flags & DEBUG):
    288         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    762     if isstring(p):
    763         pattern = p
--> 764         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    765     else:
    766         pattern = None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, pattern)
    928 
    929     try:
--> 930         p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    931     except Verbose:
    932         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    424     while True:
    425         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 426                            not nested and not items))
    427         if not sourcematch("|"):
    428             break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    814             sub_verbose = ((verbose or (add_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE)) and
    815                            not (del_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE))
--> 816             p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
    817             if not source.match(")"):
    818                 raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    424     while True:
    425         itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
--> 426                            not nested and not items))
    427         if not sourcematch("|"):
    428             break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    505 
    506         if this[0] == "\\":
--> 507             code = _escape(source, this, state)
    508             subpatternappend(code)
    509 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _escape(source, escape, state)
    400         if len(escape) == 2:
    401             if c in ASCIILETTERS:
--> 402                 raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
    403             return LITERAL, ord(escape[1])
    404     except ValueError:

error: bad escape \e at position 21
```

Comment: I'm not sure.  I can't see anything in the change logs that suggests it did.  One thing I added to the question that I forgot to mention is I also changed from non-Anaconda to Anaconda Python.  I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: What happens if you change `\e` to `e`?

Comment: Wow, suddenly it works.  Can you post an answer explaining what happened and what the reason for this is?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the escape sequence you added of `\e`. Changing that to `e` will solve your issue.

So why did this happen after you upgraded from python 3.5.2 to python 3.7.4?

Well thanks to Wiktor for pointing this out in a comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53327992/3600709) pointing me in the right direction.

According to [What's new in Python 3.7 - API and Feature Removals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> Unknown escapes consisting of `\` and an ASCII letter in replacement
>   templates for `re.sub()` were deprecated in Python 3.5, and will now
>   cause an error

Also noted in [3.7 - Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html?highlight=re%20compile#regular-expression-syntax) (the very last line in that section):

> Changed in version 3.6: Unknown escapes consisting of '\' and an ASCII
>   letter now are errors.

---

You can also see another answer (by Wiktor) with similar information here: [The “\z” anchor not working in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283192/3600709).

Comment: Very closely related to [*The “\z” anchor not working in Python regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283160/the-z-anchor-not-working-in-python-regex/53283192#53283192)